# Magento 2 how to get custom attribute value in cart page and mini cart

Tags: magento2, cart, custom, custom-attributes

Magento 2 how to get custom  attribute value in cart page and weight in mini cart.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For displaying product attribute in minicart

1. Create file **catalog_attributes.xml** Vendor/Module/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="quote_item">
     <attribute name="weight"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

2.Create **di.xml** in Vendor/Module/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem" type="Vendor\Module\CustomerData\DefaultItem" />
</config>
```

3.Create file **DefaultItem.php** inside Vendor\Module\CustomerData

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Vendor\Module\CustomerData;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

/**
 * Default item
 */
class DefaultItem extends \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem
{
         /**
         * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image
         */
        protected $imageHelper;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data
         */
        protected $msrpHelper;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
         */
        protected $urlBuilder;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ConfigurationPool
         */
        protected $configurationPool;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data
         */
        protected $checkoutHelper;

        /**
         * Escaper
         *
         * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper
         */
        private $escaper;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper,
        \Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data $msrpHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ConfigurationPool $configurationPool,
        \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data $checkoutHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper = null
    ) {
        $this->configurationPool = $configurationPool;
        $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
        $this->msrpHelper = $msrpHelper;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->checkoutHelper = $checkoutHelper;
        $this->escaper = $escaper ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Framework\Escaper::class);
    }

    protected function doGetItemData()
    {
        $imageHelper = $this->imageHelper->init($this->getProductForThumbnail(), 'mini_cart_product_thumbnail');
        $productName = $this->escaper->escapeHtml($this->item->getProduct()->getName());

        return [
            'options' => $this->getOptionList(),
            'qty' => $this->item->getQty() * 1,
            'item_id' => $this->item->getId(),
            'configure_url' => $this->getConfigureUrl(),
            'is_visible_in_site_visibility' => $this->item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility(),
            'product_id' => $this->item->getProduct()->getId(),
            'product_name' => $productName,
            'product_sku' => $this->item->getProduct()->getSku(),
            'product_url' => $this->getProductUrl(),
            'product_has_url' => $this->hasProductUrl(),
            'product_price' => $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice($this->item->getCalculationPrice()),
            'product_price_value' => $this->item->getCalculationPrice(),
            'weight' => $this->item->getProduct()->getWeight(),
            'product_image' => [
                'src' => $imageHelper->getUrl(),
                'alt' => $imageHelper->getLabel(),
                'width' => $imageHelper->getWidth(),
                'height' => $imageHelper->getHeight(),
            ],
            'canApplyMsrp' => $this->msrpHelper->isShowBeforeOrderConfirm($this->item->getProduct())
                && $this->msrpHelper->isMinimalPriceLessMsrp($this->item->getProduct()),
        ];
    }
    
}
?>
```

4.Create File **default.html** inside Current Theme app/design/frontend/Vendor/Themename/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<li class="item product product-item" data-role="product-item">
    <div class="product">
        <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url, title: product_name}" tabindex="-1" class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </a>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
        <span class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </span>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <div class="product-item-details">
            <strong class="product-item-name">
                <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
                <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, html: product_name"></a>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
                    <!-- ko text: product_name --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </strong>

            <!-- ko if: options.length -->
            <div class="product options" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": false}}'>
                <span data-role="title" class="toggle"><!-- ko i18n: 'See Details' --><!-- /ko --></span>

                <div data-role="content" class="content">
                    <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Options Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
                    <dl class="product options list">
                        <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } -->
                        <dt class="label"><!-- ko text: option.label --><!-- /ko --></dt>
                        <dd class="values">
                            <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: option.value.join('<br>')"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko ifnot: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: option.value"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </dd>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: weight -->
            <div data-bind="html: 'Weight : ' + weight"></div>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <div class="product-item-pricing">
                <!-- ko if: canApplyMsrp -->

                <div class="details-map">
                    <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Price'"></span>
                    <span class="value" data-bind="i18n: 'See price before order confirmation.'"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: canApplyMsrp -->
                <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('priceSidebar') -->
                    <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_price, as: 'price'} --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->

                <div class="details-qty qty">
                    <label class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Qty', attr: {
                           for: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty'}"></label>
                    <input data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           'data-item-qty': qty,
                           'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
                           }, value: qty"
                           type="number"
                           size="4"
                           class="item-qty cart-item-qty">
                    <button data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'update-cart-item-'+item_id,
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           title: $t('Update')
                           }"
                            class="update-cart-item"
                            style="display: none">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="product actions">
                <!-- ko if: is_visible_in_site_visibility -->
                <div class="primary">
                    <a data-bind="attr: {href: configure_url, title: $t('Edit item')}" class="action edit">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <div class="secondary">
                    <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Remove item')}"
                       class="action delete">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: i tried with this its not working please help me on this

Comment: did you use same code as i have used weight on same code ?

Comment: yes i have created new module for this and did as you did .

Comment: can you do one setting in "weight" attribute to use in "product listing" ?

Comment: any idea on Magento 2 how to get total productsweight in order summary

Comment: $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
$orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
$weight = 0;
foreach($orderItems as $item) {
    $weight += ($item->getWeight() * $item->getQty()) ;        
 }
 echo $weight;

Comment: Thanks for comment Ansar can you please elaborate how to  do it ll be helpful thanks

Comment: Thankyou for this. It worked for me.

Answer (score 13):

Create File **catalog_attributes.xml** inside Vendor/Module/etc or any existing module.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="quote_item">
     <attribute name="product-arrtibute"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

Now call that attribute in cart page or minicart like as
if dropdown type attribute

```
$_item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('product-attribute')
```

else

```
$_item->getProduct()->getProductAttribute()
```

Comment: For cart page override file Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml and write here

Comment: You can create catalog_attributes.xml file in any existing module under etc directory no need to create new one module for it

Comment: thank you very much for your support 
i did like this   <?php echo $_item->getProduct()->getProductAttribute('length') ?> is this right way  its text field attribute in admin panel

Comment: can you try this : <?php echo $_item->getProduct()->getLength() ?>

Comment: Ansar Husain  any idea on Magento 2 how to get weight in mini cart

Comment: Tomorrow i will let you know , i will make code for it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80644/discussion-between-chala-chalapathi-and-ansar-husain).

Comment: Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

2nd answer good for templates not dependent on section data, but where section data is needed (e.g. on mini-cart) the first answer is better but can be simplified to just add the additional custom attribute(s) to section data. No need to completely overwrite the core class, just extend it. So **Vender/Module/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php** just needs to have:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\CustomerData;

/**
 * Add custom attribute(s) to Default item
 */
class DefaultItem extends \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem
{
    protected function doGetItemData()
    {
        $data = parent::doGetItemData();
        $data['custom-attr-id'] = $this->item->getProduct()->getCustomAttrId();
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Now you can reference your *custom-attr-id* in the JS code, same as standard attributes.

This XML addition makes the attribute available on the quote item in PHP so you can use it where needed i.e. here when adding to section data for JS.

```
<group name="quote_item">
    <attribute name="custom-attr-id"/>
</group>
```